# R: Use character vector with column prefixes to create new columns summing values across the prefixed columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset with the following rough structure, where several columns share prefixes:

```
dataset <- data.frame(a1 =  c(1:10), a2 = c(11:20),b1=c(21:30),b2=c(31:40))
```

I want to create new columns with the row sum across each group of columns which share prefixes , so that it ends up looking like this

```
   a1 a2 b1 b2 a_sum b_sum
1   1 11 21 31    12    52
2   2 12 22 32    14    54
3   3 13 23 33    16    56
4   4 14 24 34    18    58
5   5 15 25 35    20    60
6   6 16 26 36    22    62
7   7 17 27 37    24    64
8   8 18 28 38    26    66
9   9 19 29 39    28    68
10 10 20 30 40    30    70
```

My preferred method would be somehow feed the character vector of prefixes `vec <- c("a","b")` into a mutate function which fits in a larger pipe workflow.

I have been wondering of ways to use `across` with `matches`, perhaps with some sort of `lapply` call to perform it for each element of my vector, but I fall short. I would prefer to avoid solutions which involve reshaping the data, as it is quite large and there are many columns which don't relate to this specific issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `map` or `lapply` over the `vec` vector to create the desired one-column tibbles, and finally `bind_cols()` to bind them at the end of the original data.frame.
To select columns matching a character prefix, we should usually use the `starts_with` selection helper.
The walrus (`:=`) operator allows us to dynamically generate column names as desired inside `tibble`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

vec <- c("a","b")

dataset |>
    bind_cols(vec |>
                  map(\(x) tibble("{x}_sum" := rowSums(
                      select(dataset, starts_with(x))
                  ))))

   a1 a2 b1 b2 a_sum b_sum
1   1 11 21 31    12    52
2   2 12 22 32    14    54
3   3 13 23 33    16    56
4   4 14 24 34    18    58
5   5 15 25 35    20    60
6   6 16 26 36    22    62
7   7 17 27 37    24    64
8   8 18 28 38    26    66
9   9 19 29 39    28    68
10 10 20 30 40    30    70
```

**Edit**

To enable upstream transformations to feed into this operation seamlessly, we can adapt the code to utilize the current data via `pick` rather than relying on external provision through `select`

```
dataset |> 
    mutate(bind_cols(vec |>
                  map(\(x) tibble("{x}_sum" := rowSums(
                      pick(starts_with(x))
                  )))))
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this solution in particular because it does not require code required to interpret strings as column names and such (e.g. !!! and sym()), which I think makes code harder to read. I have a few follow-up questions: 
1) I'm surprised how tibble allows the dynamic column name which may be very useful elsewhere, any resource I can use to read up on it? 
2) Is there any way that I can refer to the dataset within select() as it currently looks like in the pipeline, e.g. if I've just created some relevant columns in a mutate() right beforehand?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Modern_ibex. Glue strings as result names or column names were [introduced in dplyr/tibble in 2020](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/)

Comment: See the updated answer for a proper pipeable solution with `pick` instead of `select`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option which creates a list of expressions that are then injected into the `mutate` statement using the splice operator `!!!`:

```r
library(dplyr)

lexprs <- sapply(vec, \(x) sprintf("rowSums(pick(starts_with('%s')))", x)) |>
  rlang::parse_exprs() |>
  setNames(paste0(vec, "_sum"))

dataset |> 
  mutate(!!! lexprs)
```

Note: you can always move the `sapply` pipe directly into the `mutate` statement (see benchmark code). If you are working solely in the tidyverse then you can replace the `sapply` with (`purrr::map_chr`, `glue::glue`):

```r
map_chr(vec, \(x) glue("rowSums(pick(starts_with('{x}')))"))
```

---

**Benchmark**

On my computer this injection method is about ~ 35% faster:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


inject <- function() {
  dataset |> 
    mutate(!!! sapply(vec, \(x) sprintf("rowSums(pick(starts_with('%s')))", x)) |>
             rlang::parse_exprs() |>
             setNames(paste0(vec, "_sum")))
}

map_bind <- function() {
  dataset |>
    bind_cols(vec |>
                map(\(x) tibble("{x}_sum" := rowSums(
                  select(dataset, starts_with(x))
                ))))
}


bench::mark(
  inject(),
  map_bind(),
  min_time = 1
)

#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result        memory     time       gc      
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>        <list>     <list>     <list>  
# 1 inject()     2.26ms    2.4ms      400.    9.77KB     27.1   340    23      850ms <df [10 × 6]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 2 map_bind()   3.13ms    3.3ms      297.     9.5KB     26.9   243    22      819ms <df [10 × 6]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split.default` here

```
cbind(
  dataset,
  lapply(
    split.default(
      dataset,
      paste0(gsub("\\d+", "", names(dataset)), "_sum")
    ),
    rowSums
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   a1 a2 b1 b2 a_sum b_sum
1   1 11 21 31    12    52
2   2 12 22 32    14    54
3   3 13 23 33    16    56
4   4 14 24 34    18    58
5   5 15 25 35    20    60
6   6 16 26 36    22    62
7   7 17 27 37    24    64
8   8 18 28 38    26    66
9   9 19 29 39    28    68
10 10 20 30 40    30    70
```

Comment: This approach seems promising, but I have reservations about its applicability to various scenarios. Using gsub for string manipulation relies heavily on the specific vector of prefixes provided, which may not be suitable for general cases. What if the prefixes contain digits? Additionally, how should we handle cases where the suffixes are not exclusively numerical? I feel that somehow split.default with string manipulation may not be flexible enough, and it would be safer to use the vector of column names directly